# Unable to host or connect to service

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm using Protobuf-net to create a simple example for me to play with, but i'm unable to get it to work.

I'm getting the following error from the client:

**Status(StatusCode="Unavailable....**

**I've downloaded the example projects Client_CS, Server_CS and Shared_CS from protobuf-net.Grpc, it's the same issue when running that.**

The webpage that pops up when starting server, is using the url localhost:44312

but launchSettings saids:

```
"iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9385",
      "sslPort": 44312
    }
```

and also

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```

But startup is set to listen on port 10042 and client is looking for service on same port. Very confusing?

**Contracts:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestRequest
{
        
}

[ProtoContract]
public class TestResponse
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public ValueTask<TestResponse> TestAsync(TestRequest request, CallContext context = default)
    {
        TestResponse resp = new TestResponse();
        resp.Text = "weee";

        return new ValueTask<TestResponse>(resp);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ListenLocalhost(10042, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                });
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCodeFirstGrpc(config =>
        {
            config.ResponseCompressionLevel = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<ITestService>();

            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**lanuchSettings.json:**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9385",
      "sslPort": 44312
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Protobuf_net.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Client:**

```
GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2 = true;
using var http = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:10042");

var testService = http.CreateGrpcService<ITestService>();
var result = await testService.TestAsync(new TestRequest());
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result.Text}");

Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is just an IDE thing; by default, the IDE wants to use IIS, and frankly: it makes a mess of everything. First, set the server project to be the single startup project (right click on the project, "Set as Startup Project"):

[image]

Now, at the top of the IDE, you'll *probably* see that it it trying to use IIS:

[image]

This is the wrong configuration; change it instead to be the server project *itself*:

[image]

Now when you run the server, it should load on the correct port.

Comment: Wow, i knew it was a simple thing! it finally connects, thank you!

So, are launchSettings.json not used at all? or only when hosted in IIS?

Comment: Okay read that it's recommanded to use Host rather than WebHost now by the way.

Comment: Okay might have been a little too fast.. it seems that launchSettings.json is only used for Dev.

Comment: @Lasse there's also appsettings.json, which is more commonly used for "real" config data